# In TFS, can I get a list of all the files touched by a user for a given date range?

Tags: tfs

In TFS, I want to see how many files I modified for a day/week/etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.  You can even get fancy graphs :-)  You can either use the TFS Data Warehouse that stores this data, or you can make use of the TFS command line ([tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(VS.80).aspx)).  [tf history](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh(VS.80).aspx) would be the command you would execute for detailed information on history and see the following blog post I wrote about accessing the TFS data warehouse information from Excel:

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh(v=vs.100).aspx:

Execute all commands from the root directory of your workspace:

Show my changes for the year 2000:  (You may need to use your local date format if MM/dd/yyyy does not work for you)

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /version:D"01/01/2000"~D"01/01/2001" /user:me
```